# WebClient timeout problem

Tags: c#, webclient

I read that WebClient doesn't support timeout but I find smth strange. My WebClient class:

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    private int timeout;

    public int Timeout
    {
        get { return timeout; }
        set { timeout = value; }
    }

    public MyWebClient()
    {
        timeout = 5000;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        if (request.GetType() == typeof(HttpWebRequest))
        {
            ((HttpWebRequest)request).Timeout = timeout;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("timeout {0}", request.Timeout);

        return request;
    }
}
```

When I make request this prints:
**timeout 10000**

when I comment

```
//((HttpWebRequest)request).Timeout = timeout;
```

it prints:
**timeout 100000**

it is ok default value

but when I set:

```
((HttpWebRequest)request).Timeout = 5000;
```

it prints:
**timeout 5000**

and timouts works

Can anybody explain why I must enter the timeout value directly?

Comment: This is not really a question about WebRequest.Timeout, but rather how inheritance works in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebRequest` will not know what timeout you want to use unless you set it.

Perhaps you are confusing the setting of your class's local field `timeout` with setting the `Timeout` property on the `WebRequest` class? Or is it that you expect `WebClient` to have a `Timeout` property and to set this the request timeout automatically for you?

Unless you only want to set your own timeout for HTTP requests, the whole checking of the request type is unnecessary as `Timeout` is part of the `WebRequest` base class and so is available without a cast to `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I'm stupid. I set the wc.Timeout in another function. Problem solved